# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'exceptions' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust' (unknown location)

Tags: aws-lambda, python-3.7

I have a python script generating a CSR from a CBOR. It works fine on device locally. But when I try making it a lambda function and executing it on AWS, I got an error message "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'exceptions' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust'(unknown location)".

I'm not using layer, I just installed the modules inside the deployable package. I can confirm that the exceptions.pyi is located inside cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust. I don't know what's causing this issue. Can anyone give me some guidance, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent a few days trying to fix the importing issue but still no luck. I ended up deploying the python lambda function with container image, all problem solved.

I followed the instructions here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html#python-image-instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by following:

1. Building the lambda layer in a Linux environment.
2. Also make sure that Python versions are the same in AWS lambda and locally where you are building the lambda layer.
3. Use the following pip syntax to build packages.

> ```
> pip install --upgrade <pakage names> --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: -t .
> ```